# Combine and join given data in specific format

Tags: c#, permutation, combinatorics

I have the following data for example:

```
YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T
YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T
YELLOW,SMALL,STRETCH,CHILD,F
YELLOW,SMALL,DIP,ADULT,F
YELLOW,SMALL,DIP,CHILD,F
YELLOW,LARGE,STRETCH,ADULT,T
YELLOW,LARGE,STRETCH,ADULT,T
YELLOW,LARGE,STRETCH,CHILD,F
YELLOW,LARGE,DIP,ADULT,F
YELLOW,LARGE,DIP,CHILD,F
PURPLE,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T
PURPLE,SMALL,STRETCH,ADULT,T
PURPLE,SMALL,STRETCH,CHILD,F
PURPLE,SMALL,DIP,ADULT,F
PURPLE,SMALL,DIP,CHILD,F
PURPLE,LARGE,STRETCH,ADULT,T
PURPLE,LARGE,STRETCH,ADULT,T
PURPLE,LARGE,STRETCH,CHILD,F
PURPLE,LARGE,DIP,ADULT,F
PURPLE,LARGE,DIP,CHILD,F
```

I need to generate the following sets of data (note the columns of above data will generate number of data below) If there are 5 columns, there will be 4 sets of data, first with single column, second with 2, third with 3, and so on. The last column is omitted and is the CLASS column with which all the data is joined and the numbers are the occurrences of it in the above given data.

```
--------------------------------------------------
1 column
--------------------------------------------------
YELLOW  T   4   
SMALL   T   4   
STRETCH T   8   
ADULT   T   8   
YELLOW  F   6   
SMALL   F   6   
STRETCH F   4   
CHILD   F   8   
DIP F   8   
ADULT   F   4   
LARGE   T   4   
LARGE   F   6   
PURPLE  T   4   
PURPLE  F   6   
--------------------------------------------------
2 columns
--------------------------------------------------
YELLOW  SMALL   T   2   
YELLOW  STRETCH T   4   
YELLOW  ADULT   T   4   
SMALL   STRETCH T   4   
SMALL   ADULT   T   4   
STRETCH ADULT   T   8   
YELLOW  SMALL   F   3   
YELLOW  STRETCH F   2   
YELLOW  CHILD   F   4   
SMALL   STRETCH F   2   
SMALL   CHILD   F   4   
STRETCH CHILD   F   4   
YELLOW  DIP F   4   
YELLOW  ADULT   F   2   
SMALL   DIP F   4   
SMALL   ADULT   F   2   
DIP ADULT   F   4   
DIP CHILD   F   4   
YELLOW  LARGE   T   2   
LARGE   STRETCH T   4   
LARGE   ADULT   T   4   
YELLOW  LARGE   F   3   
LARGE   STRETCH F   2   
LARGE   CHILD   F   4   
LARGE   DIP F   4   
LARGE   ADULT   F   2   
PURPLE  SMALL   T   2   
PURPLE  STRETCH T   4   
PURPLE  ADULT   T   4   
PURPLE  SMALL   F   3   
PURPLE  STRETCH F   2   
PURPLE  CHILD   F   4   
PURPLE  DIP F   4   
PURPLE  ADULT   F   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   T   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   F   3
--------------------------------------------------
3 columns
--------------------------------------------------
YELLOW  SMALL   STRETCH T   2   
YELLOW  SMALL   ADULT   T   2   
YELLOW  STRETCH ADULT   T   4   
SMALL   STRETCH ADULT   T   4   
YELLOW  SMALL   STRETCH F   1   
YELLOW  SMALL   CHILD   F   2   
YELLOW  STRETCH CHILD   F   2   
SMALL   STRETCH CHILD   F   2   
YELLOW  SMALL   DIP F   2   
YELLOW  SMALL   ADULT   F   1   
YELLOW  DIP ADULT   F   2   
SMALL   DIP ADULT   F   2   
YELLOW  DIP CHILD   F   2   
SMALL   DIP CHILD   F   2   
YELLOW  LARGE   STRETCH T   2   
YELLOW  LARGE   ADULT   T   2   
LARGE   STRETCH ADULT   T   4   
YELLOW  LARGE   STRETCH F   1   
YELLOW  LARGE   CHILD   F   2   
LARGE   STRETCH CHILD   F   2   
YELLOW  LARGE   DIP F   2   
YELLOW  LARGE   ADULT   F   1   
LARGE   DIP ADULT   F   2   
LARGE   DIP CHILD   F   2   
PURPLE  SMALL   STRETCH T   2   
PURPLE  SMALL   ADULT   T   2   
PURPLE  STRETCH ADULT   T   4   
PURPLE  SMALL   STRETCH F   1   
PURPLE  SMALL   CHILD   F   2   
PURPLE  STRETCH CHILD   F   2   
PURPLE  SMALL   DIP F   2   
PURPLE  SMALL   ADULT   F   1   
PURPLE  DIP ADULT   F   2   
PURPLE  DIP CHILD   F   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   STRETCH T   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   ADULT   T   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   STRETCH F   1   
PURPLE  LARGE   CHILD   F   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   DIP F   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   ADULT   F   1   
--------------------------------------------------
4 columns
--------------------------------------------------
YELLOW  SMALL   STRETCH ADULT   T   2   
YELLOW  SMALL   STRETCH CHILD   F   1   
YELLOW  SMALL   DIP ADULT   F   1   
YELLOW  SMALL   DIP CHILD   F   1   
YELLOW  LARGE   STRETCH ADULT   T   2   
YELLOW  LARGE   STRETCH CHILD   F   1   
YELLOW  LARGE   DIP ADULT   F   1   
YELLOW  LARGE   DIP CHILD   F   1   
PURPLE  SMALL   STRETCH ADULT   T   2   
PURPLE  SMALL   STRETCH CHILD   F   1   
PURPLE  SMALL   DIP ADULT   F   1   
PURPLE  SMALL   DIP CHILD   F   1   
PURPLE  LARGE   STRETCH ADULT   T   2   
PURPLE  LARGE   STRETCH CHILD   F   1   
PURPLE  LARGE   DIP ADULT   F   1   
PURPLE  LARGE   DIP CHILD   F   1
```

So there can be even 50 columns and there can be 80 or even more.

The complexity is also that there can be 0 and 1 instead of words and we need to match with the same columns.

Hope you got the question.

I have made the following code to generate the 1st column. Main problem is for the rest columns.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lsClasses.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < lsUniqueOps.Count; j++)
                {
                    int count = FindInOrignalList(orignalList, lsClasses[i], lsUniqueOps[j]);
                    if (count != 0)
                    {
                        List<string> checkedItem = new List<string>();
                        checkedItem.Add(lsUniqueOps[j][0]);
                        checkedItem.Add(lsUniqueOps[j][1]);
                        checkedItem.Add(lsClasses[i]);
                        checkedItem.Add(count.ToString());
                        lsFirstItemSet.Add(checkedItem);
                    }
                }
            }

--------------------------------------------------

private static int FindInOrignalList(List<List<string>> orignalList, string lsClass, List<string> lsUniqueOp)
        {
            List<List<string>> tmpList = new List<List<string>>();
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < orignalList.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < orignalList[i].Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (orignalList[i][j] + "," + orignalList[i][orignalList[i].Count - 1] == lsUniqueOp[0] + "," + lsClass)
                        count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
```

Comment: please show instantiations for `lsClasses`, `lsUniqueOps` and `originalList`.

Comment: orignal list is the main data set. Unique ops are yellow, purple, dip, large, adult, etc all unique words. and classes are T and F here.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly, yo only list the occurences that are not market with "F" at the end. You only get "T"'s. Is that correct? If so, you can start by

1. removing the lines that are F'ed, since they'll never cause any upcount,
2. removing the last column fully (since only T's are there andthe existence of a line already implies its truity)
3. telling me if this is a homework (in which case you're at a junior level and need a different explanation than a senior programmer).

I'll assume that you are the savvy type. Then you might apply LINQ and a suitable data structure to compute the occurrences. Just of the top of my head - `DataSet` and company might be a good choice. `Dictionary` might be an other.

Comment: Hello, no what happens here is we need to check every column with the F or T. Like how many time Yellow and T occurred, DIP and F occurred and so on. Then proceeding to the next part, these columns are joined with other columns like how many time did Yellow, DIP and T occurred, etc. untill the total columns-1.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair My bad! In any case, I'd give a try to a `Dictionary` and use the x nubmer of columns as keys. Does that help?

Comment: @MuhammadUmair If you find the reply helpful, mark it so. If not, explain why so we can refine it.